# Which language is suitable for Linux and related programming?

Tags: linux, programming-languages

What would be the best language if I want to develop a range of Linux related things. I want to make kernel patches, Linux programs, contribute with other projects, etc. Where and with which language do I start?

Comment: C sells C shells on the C shore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to decide which language is going to be useful to you is to look at the source for the projects to which you wish to contribute. Take a look around popular code repositories, such as [github](/questions/tagged/github), [google-code](/questions/tagged/google-code) and [sourceforge](/questions/tagged/sourceforge).

Diving into a language like [python](/questions/tagged/python) may be useful for some scientific projects, but not at all useful for something low-level like [linux-kernel](/questions/tagged/linux-kernel) development.

> I want to make kernel patches

The [Linux kernel source tree](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) is currently:

- 96.5 % [c](/questions/tagged/c)
- 2.2% [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly)
- 1.3% "other" (documentation and [makefile](/questions/tagged/makefile)s, presumably).

So start with [The  C Programming Language](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0131103628/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=0131103628&linkCode=as2&tag=johnsydotorg-21) and go from there!

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do kernel work and a variety of other Linux core things, then C (followed by C++) would be your starting point. You also need to throw in a healthy does of bash shell programming. And `gcc` is the compilation tool of choice. The kernel is nearly all `C` and a lot of apps use `C++`

Comment: Can you suggest some tutorials or something?

Comment: Lots of choices out there you can Google. Maybe start here: http://www.wikihow.com/Learn-to-Program-in-C

Comment: @HafizMohammadShayanTariq the canonical reference is Kernighan & Ritche's book, the 2nd edition of which is a pretty good tutorial if you already know some programming.

Answer (score 1):

You should know C (for kernel patches) and Bash (so you can actually use Linux). Maybe also Python (for general scripting).

Comment: Please also suggest some good tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Learning Python is a good start, if you are familiar with Object Oriented programming. Shell scripting can help you a lot too.